# From a general perspective, why are we more likely to remember wanting to do something, but not specifically what it is?

Tags: memory, brain

I have experienced several mind pops and instant recalls based on triggered events, and some might come suddenly, or they might gradually appear.

Sometimes, though, I remember something that I would like to write down or look up on-line, but sometime later, when I am reminded about it, all I can remember was that I wanted to write it down or look it up, but I wouldn't be able to remember what it was.

So, what theories or hypotheses might suggest for why this happens frequently?

Comment: i found a source that might explain a little bit about the process of encoding memories, but I don{t fully understand it enough to write an actual answer. https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-psychology/chapter/the-process-of-forgetting/